# How to make my rails app discoverable by search engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my rails app deployed on heroku, I then bought a custom domain with a local web hosting service, how can I make my website indexed by google search engine, I have the indexing method suggested by google. but none of them worked, is it because I have pointed my custom domain to the Heroku one? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart

Comment: Hey @mike, welcome to stackoverflow! However you question is not a programming question, but one of SEO. So it is kind of off topic, maybe you can see if there is another stackexchange forum or some subreddit that can help you with that! Good luck with your app!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO and very broad.